# An applicationIconBadgeNumber doesn't updated or increased

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I'm new to the iOS Development! I've tried to create an app with the `UILocalNotification`. Here's what I've done:

```
func createLocalNotification(structure:Structure) {

        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.category = "CATEGORY"
        localNotification.alertBody = "\(structure.messageBody)"
        localNotification.alertAction = "see"
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        localNotification.userInfo = ["uuid":structure.UUID]
        localNotification.fireDate = structure.date
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

        print(localNotification)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

It works well! My problem line is an `applicationBadgeNumber`. This `property` seems to works. But does not increased when an app is inactive state. And then an app is launched Xcode gives me an error like so:

Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

What does means? What's the wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting up registration settings with `Sound` and `Badge` ?

Something like this: (A part taken from [this link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/21/2/scheduling-notifications-uilocalnotification))

```
@IBAction func registerLocal(sender: AnyObject) {
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have enough repuation to comment yet. The only way you're going to be able to dynamically set the badge number when your application isn't running is with push notifications. You'll have to track the updates on the server side

**It is not possible to update dynamically the badge number with local notifications while your app is in the background. You have to use push notifications**.